# How can I get the index of the pane underneath the current pane in tmux?

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm trying to get the index of the pane directly under the currently selected pane in tmux so that I can call `tmux run-shell` on that pane from vim.

Suppose I have a tmux pane layout like below:

```
|---------------------------|
|             |             |
|      0      |      1      |
|             |             |
|---------------------------|
|                           |
|             2             |
|                           |
|---------------------------|
```

I know that I can get my current pane number by running:

`tmux list-panes | grep "active" | cut -d':' -f1`

for this case, we will say it is `0`

This was the first solution that came to my mind to get the index:

```
#!/bin/bash

CUR_PANE=$(tmux list-panes | grep "active" | cut -d':' -f1)
tmux select-pane -D

UNDER_PANE=$(tmux list-panes | grep "active" | cut -d':' -f1)
tmux select-pane -U

# In case the script is used on the bottom
# pane and `select-pane` wrapped around
if [ ! $UNDER_PANE -gt $CUR_PANE ]; then
    echo "No pane under current."
    exit 1
fi

echo $CUR_PANE
echo $UNDER_PANE
```

But this seems like a quick and dirty approach to me as I actually have to *switch* to the pane, then back to the original.

Is there a cleaner way to do this without leaving the current pane in tmux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `tmux display` which is alias of `tmux display-message`: [Reference](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#STATUS_LINE)

```
$ tmux display -p -t '{down-of}' '#{pane_index}'
```

`-t {down-of}` means take information from pane underneath the active pane: [Reference](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#COMMANDS)

`#{pane_index}` means format the message with panel index: [Reference](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#FORMATS)

`-p` means write the message to stdout

Comment: Awesome, I imagined there was some one line solution like this. I had to change `pane_id` to `pane_index`, but it works amazingly and as expected. Thank you very much.